# I'm getting an Error running rvm make while installing Ruby

Tags: ruby, terminal, path, rvm, ruby-install

I am trying to install ruby on my Mac and every time I follow the instructions online to install ruby; I'm getting deeper down in the rabbit hole.I think I messed up my .zshrc and path variables. I've attached relevant screenshots.

[Error when i install ruby 3.0, where ruby command and rvm list on terminal.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOXad.png)

[Let's look at my bashrc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43y2x.png)

[I don't know what happened here but this is my one line .zshrc file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nCay.png)

[When I run brew doctor on the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vV5rl.png)

- I'm expecting to have my path variables configured properly
- I want to have ruby installed on my system with no errors
- Also could I just copy someone's path files? Or each path is unique apart from the user profile names.